# Kafka MetricsReporter backed by Spring Boot Actuator

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-boot-actuator, spring-kafka

I decided to go back to my idea of integrating Kafka Metrics with Spring Boot Actuator, which I've mentioned here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6227

As of now I have a separate "sandbox" project with working code, which I want to merge into Spring Boot. And now I'm a bit confused. Part of my tests require powermock to Mock Kafka's "super-secured" class:

```java
package org.apache.kafka.common.metrics;

// some imports...

public final class KafkaMetric implements Metric {
    private MetricName metricName;
    private final Object lock;
    private final Time time;
    private final Measurable measurable;
    private MetricConfig config;

    KafkaMetric(Object lock, MetricName metricName, Measurable measurable, MetricConfig config, Time time) {
        this.metricName = metricName;
        this.lock = lock;
        this.measurable = measurable;
        this.config = config;
        this.time = time;
    }

    // some good code here, but no public constructor and the class is final... of course.

}
```

But powermock is not used in Spring Boot.

What should I do?

1. Add latest stable powermock - both in spring-boot-dependencies and spring-boot-actuator.
2. Add latest stable powermock to spring-boot-actuator only - let it be a hidden secret helper.
3. Exclude the tests which require powermock.
4. Forget about Kafka Metrics, they're huge and scary and nobody wants them in our nice and friendly Spring Boot Actuator.

Comment: How about to use `Metrics.addMetric()` to create `KafkaMetric` instance and than react to it via your `KafkaStatisticsProvider.metricChange()`, which you will register in the `Metrics` instance before testing? Instead of Powermock, of course. Not familiar with Kafka Metrics, but I forked your project. Looks simple, but need some time to figure out what's going on. Will come back to you from Monday, if don't find time on weekend.

Comment: This answers the question, case is closed, thank you. Looking forward to hearing from you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having your confirmation in the comments, I'm just copying here my comment as a valid answer to close the question properly.

You can try to use `Metrics.addMetric()` to create `KafkaMetric` instance and than react to it via your `KafkaStatisticsProvider.metricChange()`, which you will register in the `Metrics` instance before testing. Instead of Powermock, of course.

I will try to find time next week to contribute to your actuator project that part to avoid Powermock.

Comment: I've done did this change here: https://github.com/stepio/spring-boot/commit/83f853f780b58c805c8c1cdc8ed1a394a5c04f9a

Comment: That's cool! I that should be somehow mentioned in Boot issue

Comment: You mean that I should create some issue for metrics support in Spring Boot project? As of now I don't think that the code is ready for PR. I'd like to invent something to link this reporter with your auto-configuration of Spring Kafka to write the metrics automatically and make the change complete.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look to the `MetricReader` implementation for the Boot auto-configuration? The main trick that it is fully different story from the core auto-configuration. For example `PublicMetricsAutoConfiguration.IntegrationMetricsConfiguration`